# how do I access the data of a NSMutableIndexSet

Tags: ios

I have a NSMutableIndexSet of:

```
<NSMutableIndexSet: 0x85825c0>[number of indexes: 2 (in 2 ranges), indexes: (2 4)]
```

How do I set the number of indexes (2) to a property like an int and indexes to an array (2 4)

Comment: @H2CO3 can you please show me in the documentation where it tells me how to do this?

Comment: I meant this (official class reference by Apple): [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes I got that, but where in the documentation does it talk about accessing the data in the index with enumerateIndexUsingBlock as Martin showed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `count` method to get the number of indexes in the set.
With
`enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:` you can enumerate all indexes in the set and add them
to an `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSUInteger numberOfIndexes = [set count];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[set enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [array addObject:@(idx)];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Comment: ok, sorry but I am still confused. where is the array that in this case would contain 2 and 4?

Comment: ah I see ok this makes more sense and works correctly, thank you. Looks like I will have to learn more about blocks because I dont understand them.

Comment: @BluGeni: You are welcome. - Perhaps have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html.